# Does iOS' 8 iCloud Drive enable different users to share files?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, ios8, osx-yosemite

C.f. Apple website page on iCloud Drive:
http://www.apple.com/ios/ios8/icloud-drive/

I understand iCloud Drive makes easy for an individual user to save a file to the cloud and work on it from any of *his or her own* devices, i.e. a solo use case.

My question is: with the new iCloud Drive, can *different* users, with different Apple accounts (not necessarily in the same family), share and collaborate on files? E.g. Could an iOS 8 app help a bunch of users collaborate on, say, a video editing project where all the heavy raw footage video files are shared on iCloud Drive?

Comment: Don't know the answer, but you probably will have to create folder and share the folder.  It would be surprised if every one has access to it by default.

Answer (score 2):

CloudKit is for backend app usage for developers. It has nothing to do with iCloud Drive user accounts. Time will tell how sharing works with iCloud Drive.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question: yes, it is possible thanks to CloudKit, c.f.
https://developer.apple.com/icloud/documentation/cloudkit-storage/